# Powershell: Copy files from network to PC's base off PC model

Tags: powershell, loops, copy, ping

I am currently tasked with taking a list of IPs with their computer models in a excel spreadsheet. Example:

0.0.0.1    HP ProBook 640 G1

0.0.0.3    HP ProBook 640 G4

0.0.0.4    HP ProBook 640 G1

0.0.0.2    HP ProBook 640 G2

0.0.0.5    HP ProBook 640 G1

0.0.0.6    HP ProBook 640 G3

0.0.0.9    HP ProBook 640 G3

0.0.0.8    HP ProBook 640 G2

I first need to ping each IP to see if the PC is up. If the PC is up then I need to copy a specific group files from the network to the PC based off the PC model. So for example:

If the PC 0.0.0.1 is up and its model is HP ProBook 640 G1, I would need to copy the files from the \network\HP_ProBook_640_G1 directory to C:\path\to\directory. If the PC is 0.0.0.3 and the model is HP ProBook 640 G4 then I'd copy the files from the \network\HP_ProBook_640_G4 directory to C:\path\to\directory. How would I script this via powershell to iterate, identify if the host is live and identify the PC model, then copy the files from a specified network directory to the specified C:\path\to\directory? Each directory contains 4 files in total. Here is the IP portion I have:

```
$Output= @()
$names = Get-content "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\abc.txt"
foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
   $Output+= "$name,up"
   Write-Host "$Name,up"
  }
  else{
    $Output+= "$name,down"
    Write-Host "$Name,down"
  }
}
$Output | Out-file "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\results.txt"
```

This ping command works but doesn't pair the IP to the PC model.

Here is the copy portion I have:

```
$File="C:\path\to\directory";
$Exists=Test-Path $File;

If($Exists-eq$TRUE)
    {Write-Host `nFile already exists.}
Else
    {Write-Host `nFile not found. Copying file. Please wait...;
    Copy-Item -Path "\\network\HP_ProBook_640_G1" -Destination "C:\path\to\directory"-Recurse;
Write-Host `nFile has been successfully copied.}
```

This copy script works as well (sorry if it's sloppy, formatting it in stackoverflow made it come out wonky) but I'm having issues figuring out how to iterate if the IP = PC model, copy all files from \network\PC_Model to c:\path\to\directory. I also apologize for the explanation. Any help would be appreciated. I normally use python but this PC does not have Python on it and I cannot install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do all of this in one loop, provided you have permissions to write to the C drives on each of the computers of course.

Also, I would suggest creating a CSV file as output so you can store more information in a structured way.

```
# read the list, omit empty lines
$names = Get-content "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\abc.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }

$result = foreach ($item in $names) {
    # split the string in the IP address or name and the model
    $pc, $model = $item -split '\s+', 2
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $pc -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        # create the paths to copy from and to Both paths in UNC format
        $sourcePath = Join-Path -Path '\\network' -ChildPath ($model.Trim() -replace ' ', '_')
        $targetPath = '\\{0}\C$\path\to\directory' -f $pc
        if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $targetPath -PathType Container)) {
            $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory
        }
        Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $targetPath -Recurse -Force
        # output for $result
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Computer = $pc
            Model    = $model
            Status   = "Files copied from $($sourcePath)"
        }
    }
    else {
        # output for $result
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Computer = $pc
            Model    = $model
            Status   = "Computer is unreachable"
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\results.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```